# How to disable script component while in game?

Tags: unity, c#, component-based

I'm trying to make a C# script to disable the First person controller script component for my character. I'm doing this so that while I'm controlling something else such as a vehicle, the only control script enabled at the time is the vehicle, and vice versa for when I'm not in the vehicle.

I did find a tutorial on the Unity Web site for Enabling and Disabling components but it uses a light component as an example, and I have no idea of how to do the same thing with a script component. I really appreciate any help I can get to solve this problem.

Thank you

This is the code in C# provided by the tutorial:

```
public class EnableComponents : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Light myLight;


    void Start ()
    {
        myLight = GetComponent<Light>();
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Light` is the script. In your case your script name will come there. Its simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that you have a script like so:

```
public class CustomScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
     //does some stuff
    }
    void Update ()
    {
     //does some other stuff
    }
}
```

Now, let's also assume you have a gameObject which has this script and also another script to enable / disable this script:

```
public class EnableDisableForCustomScript : MonoBehaviour
{
CustomScript myScript;
    void Start ()
    {
         myScript = gameObject.GetComponent<CustomScript>();
    }
    void Update ()
    { 
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            myScript.enabled = !myScript.enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also extend the last part with two keys that will enable or disable at will:

```
void Update ()
    { 
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            myScript.enabled = true; //enable the script when space is pressed
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            myScript.enabled = false; //disable the script when escape is pressed
        }
    }
```

Remember, you need both scripts on the same object or you need to first find that object in the scene and then the component named as your script.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to change in that script is the call to [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html). Change `<Light>` to the name of the class which implements your 1st person controller behavior. So when your first person controller is implemented as a `class FirstPersonController  : MonoBehaviour`, get a reference to it with `GetComponent<FirstPersonController>()`. [The `.enabled` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) is inherited from MonoBehaviour, so it is available on every scripted behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable script component by using the following syntax,

```
GameObject.Find("Cube").GetComponent<MoveObject>().enabled = false;
```

Here I disable the MoveObject script from the object named Cube.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
//your other object
public GameObject otherobj;

// your secound script name
public string scr;

void Start () {
    (otherobj.GetComponent(scr) as MonoBehaviour).enabled = false;
}
```